# Mongo Aggregation, merge object that have same key value, in the same array

Tags: aggregation-framework

I have spend my whole night trying to figure out how can i merge, objects that is in the same array, with the same key value into one. Here is my document after some aggregation.

```
   bedspaces:Array
    0:Object
       _id:5dcfec97becbce2edcd1b977
       number:1
       decks:Object
    1:Object
      _id:5dcfec97becbce2edcd1b977
      number:1
      decks:Object <-- add content of this object, to the decks object
    2:Object
      _id:5dcfef0cbecbce2edcd1b987
      number:2
      decks:Object
```

What my desired output is to merge that second object with the first since they have the same number, and object id and "ADD", the content of the decks object to the decks object in the first object.

```
 0:Object
       _id:5dcfec97becbce2edcd1b977
       number:1
       decks:Object <--- deck content is added here
 1:Object
      _id:5dcfef0cbecbce2edcd1b987
      number:2
      decks:Object
```

I know i need to unwind the bedspaces array, but i cant put back the arrays back together.Also my data is dynamically generated. So i need a robust robust way of doing this. Any help will do.